# datapusher log shows `403 Forbidden` error every-time, while `Updating` resource files in CKAN

Tags: ckan

I'm using ckan 2.7.2 (Docker), Whenever I try to **update** any resource file (via GUI), Ckan is throwing an error i.e. **403 forbidden** and data could not successfully upload to the `DataStore`. Because of that file preview is showing old content, although we are able to download the new updated file (with updated data). whether I try to upload(update) that file directly to `DataStore` by  `Upload to DataStore` option, it throws same error i.e. **403 Forbidden error**.

below are the logs of **datapusher.error.log** file:

```
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.423279 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] Deleting "<resource_id>" from datastore.
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.469999 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py:340: SubjectAltNameWarning: Certificate for demo.ckan.org has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.470014 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]   SubjectAltNameWarning
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534169 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534185 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534187 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534189 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]     retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534190 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 463, in push_to_datastore
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534192 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]     delete_datastore_resource(resource_id, api_key, ckan_url)
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534193 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 199, in delete_datastore_resource
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534195 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]     good_status=(201, 200, 404), ignore_no_success=True)
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534196 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 160, in check_response
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534197 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408]     response=response.text)
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534198 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] HTTPError: CKAN bad response. Status code: 403 Forbidden. At: https://demo.ckan.org/ckan/api/3/action/datastore_delete. status=403 url=https://demo.ckan.org/ckan/api/3/action/datastore_delete response=<html>\r
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534200 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534201 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] <body bgcolor="white">\r
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534203 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534204 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] <hr><center>nginx</center>\r
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534205 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] </body>\r
[Tue Jun 23 10:56:50.534206 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 725:tid 140031474673408] </html>\r
```

**Please suggest, how to fix this.
Thanks:)**